# Socket.io 1.0 storing user information in the socket

Tags: security, socket.io

Is the socket.user readable to the client or goes in transit? Or does it stay private?

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    //handshake ok
    socket.user = ourUserData;
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('hello', 'cool');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It stays private. Server `socket` object only shares data that you explicitly send to the client with `emit` or similar methods.

However, I would not populate `socket` object with my own data because it may be confusing for other teammates. Instead I would create a new object, say, `usersData` with socket ID as a key and your data as a value.

Here is an example:

```
var usersData = {};
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    //handshake ok
    usersData[socket.id] = ourUserData;
    next();
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('hello', 'cool');
    //do something with usersData[socket.id]

    //don't forget to delete the disconnected user's data
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        delete usersData[socket.id];
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cool thanks!  This helps a lot. I do wonder, why create another dictionary with and ID.  Seems that then you have to handle deleting it and stuff rather than have it organically in the socket object. I'll sleep on this.

Comment: This is of course an ideological question. Someone prefers to leave 3rd-party lib's objects intact, someone not. The choice is yours :)